# How to check if SQL Server 2012 Shared Management Objects (SMO) is installed

Tags: sql-server, smo

To configure an install assistent, I have to check if SQL Server 2012 SMO is already installed. I found some answers for older versions of SQL Server (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-the-presence-of-smo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502047/how-to-find-if-sql-server-2008-management-objects-installed)) with the solutions to check the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database` but this doesn't work for me. This registry key doesn't exists at Windows Vista and Windows 7, I think there are changes with the version 2012 of the SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking for an installed component, then the best bet is to check the uninstall registry key.

On my machine the key value for "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects  (x64)" is this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{43A5C316-9521-49C3-B9B6-FCE5E1005DF0}
```

There may be a different key entry for the 32bit version if you need that, but this is the way I always did software install checks when I was an SCCM admin.

EDIT: As it seems that Microsoft change the uninstall key every version making it difficult to keep track of the installation this way, there is another key here which is probably a good one to check:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SharedManagementObjects\CurrentVersion
```

You could check the value of this to see if it's greater than 11 and if not (or it doesn't exist) do your install.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On my machine the key in the registry is "...{FA0A244E-F3C2-4589-B42A-3D522DE79A42}". Maybe every machine has another GUID? So how could I use this registry key if every machine has another GUID?

Comment: It should be the GUID for the package which should be the same on each machine, what version of the software is installed on yours?  Mine is 11.1.3000.0, it may be that different versions have different GUIDs, which is a bit annoying but not an insurmountable problem.

Comment: On my machine version 11.0.2100.60 is installed, that could be an explanation. But I think that your idea is hard to implement... Every version > 11.0 should be accepted by my install assistent and I can't update the install assistent each time Microsoft release a new SMO. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: OK, I've had a poke about on my machine and think I've found another suitable key, have a look at the edit in my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: Great! The works, thank you very much! Now, I check if HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SharedManagementObjects\CurrentVersion\Version is greater 11

Comment: ARHG... I've got a new problem. I use advancedinstaller.com to configure the installation and this application generates a setup.exe which is always a 32bit application. Now, if the installer access the registry of a 64bit OS, the registry key gets forwarded to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ and it doesn't find the version number of the 64bit installation of SMO. Any idea to solve this? Maybe use another registry key outside HKLM\SOFTWARE?